# Can static storage (mostly data segment) cause segmentation fault?

Tags: x86, segmentation-fault, lazy-initialization, data-segment

`static` storage is decided at compilation time. However, consider the scenario where we have lot of lazy initialization in functions:

```
void foo ()
{
  static int a[1000];
}
```

I am not discussing the coding practice here, but the technical aspect. As many such *other functions like* `foo()` are executed, those many `static` variables will be introduced on data segment.

Will compiler take the lazy initialization also in the account *while allocating space for data segment*. If 'No' then, will it cause segmentation fault at runtime while the code is executing ? (more likely to happen when lot of `static` data inside `template` methods).

Comment: Pick a language. C and C++ are distinct.

Comment: @Tomalak, This is applicable to both of them.

Comment: You're asking for specific semantics of a language. You have assumed that the answer is the same for both, but meta-data about answers have no place in questions.

Comment: @Tomalak His example is clearly well within the common subset of C and C++.  As part of the common subset, one would hope that the answer would be the same in both cases.

Comment: @James: Perhaps I'm reacting too strongly but I find that almost every time a question is tagged both `c` and `c++` the OP either has a fundamental misunderstanding of what they _are_, or has made an assumption about what the correct answer will relate to. _We_ know that the answer lies within the common subset, but the _question_ doesn't know that.

Comment: It's applicable to any language that has static data.

Comment: @DeadMG, removing C/C++ will not help to get larger audience to this question. If you wish you can add `programming-language` tab.

Comment: @iammilind: Larger audience is irrelevant. What matters is that it is tagged correctly, and neither C or C++ have any notion of a data segment, if such a thing even exists anymore, it is a platform specific thing and all compilers for all languages will need it.

Comment: @Tomalak In general, you're right, but the nature of the question, and the way it was posed, makes me think that this might be the exception.  (Or he wants an answer for both languages.)

Comment: @DeadMG: But they _do_ define the semantics of a static-duration object.

Answer (score 5):

Just because the initialization is lazy, the allocation isn't.  The standard requires all static variables (including local variables) to be zero initialized before the start of program.  And in fact, static means just that (in this case): the space for the variable is present for the entire lifetime of the program.

Comment: +1, but if the space is allocated for all the `static` variable then how about `template`s. How they will be allocated the space.

Comment: @iammilind - No difference. The compiler knows how many templates are instantiated and can add up the space needed. It is all determined at compile time.

Comment: @iammilind: Templates don't change anything. Templates are instantiated at build-time, and each time it happens you get a function out of it. Just like your `foo()`.

Comment: @iammilind There are no templates in an executable.  When a template is instantiated, it becomes a function or a class, just like any other function or class (almost).

Answer (score 3):

1) there wont be "many" variables for one thing. a static variable in function/method scope is very much like a global variable.

2) there is no lazy init as is most likely initialzed during app start-up, along with all other global variables.

3) i see no reason for a fault

[Read more about Static(C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx)

EDIT: removed statement about zero'ing out

Comment: It _will_ "zero out the buffer"; objects with static storage are zero-initialised.

Comment: hehe yes i was right in the middle of checking that in VS2010.  that was not always the case in older versions of VS

Comment: It should have been. If not, then that was a pretty flagrant violation of the language by VS. Not that I'm too surprised.

Answer (score 2):

> As many such foo()s are executed, those many static variables will be introduced on data segment.

No. You only get one `foo()::a`. That's kind of the whole point.

> Will compiler take the lazy initialization also in the account while
>   allocating space for data segment. If 'No' then, will it cause
>   segmentation fault at runtime while the code is executing ? (more
>   likely to happen when lot of static data inside template methods).

You appear to be asking whether the `.data` section will run out of space (and thus further writes to it may cause corruption errors) if you have too many `static` objects.

Well, as noted above, it's known at compile-time how much space you'll need for static storage (for function template instantiations too). You do *not* get more `foo()::a` every time you call the function, so there is *no run-time element* to determining how much space will be required.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, he was asking about allocation, and not initialization.  (His example, of course, didn't have any initialization, except for the zero initialization always present in static variables.)

Comment: @James: Aha, I think I see now.

Comment: `As many` **such** `foo()s are executed`, I meant other functions which are like `foo()`; not the `foo()` alone.

Comment: @iammilind: You mean as many functions with static-duration objects inside of them? Well, the compiler/linker can see all of them at build-time too...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, you won't segfault.

In the example below, `abc` is in the [Data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) and `def` and `x` are in BSS.

```
#include <iostream>

int abc = 123;
int def;

int foo (int i) {
    static int x (i);
    return x;
}

int main () {
    std :: cout << foo (100) << " " << foo (200);
}
```

This example prints out "100 100": initialisastion of function-scope `static` objects happens during the first invocation only.

Storage for `x` is the same as if it was a global variable like `def`.

Templates are basically the same, except if `foo` was parameterised by templates, there would be one `x` for each instantination.